# Haskell: Are type variables in "where" clauses in the same namespace with their parents?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In the following snippet (I have abstracted all other trivial parts)

```
data T s = T (s -> s)

foo :: T s -> s -> s
foo (T f) x = bar x where
    bar :: s -> s
    bar a = f a
```

I got following error

```
Couldn't match expected type `s1' with actual type `s'
  `s1' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for bar :: s1 -> s1 at /tmp/test.hs:5:12
  `s' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for foo :: T s -> s -> s at /tmp/test.hs:3:8
In the return type of a call of `f'
In the expression: f a
In an equation for `bar': bar a = f a
```

my guess was that the type variables in `bar`'s signature don't share the namespace with `foo`, so the compiler can't infer that the two `s` actually mean the same type.

Then I found this page [Scoped type variables](https://wiki.haskell.org/Scoped_type_variables), which suggests that I can use `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`, which didn't help. I got the same error.

Comment: As the examples on the wiki (should) imply, you need a `forall s` in the type signature of `foo` to actually use it with `ScopedTypeVariables`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are type variables in “where” clauses in the same namespace with their parents?

No*. This gets a little bit easier if you think of `foo :: s -> s` in terms of `foo :: forall s. s -> s`. After all, a type variable indicates that the function works for any type `s`. Let's add explicit quantifications to your code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}

data T s = T (s -> s)

foo :: forall s. T s -> s -> s
foo (T f) x = bar x where
    bar :: forall s. s -> s
    bar a = f a
```

As you can see, there are two `forall s.` there. But the one in `bar` is wrong. After all, you cannot choose *any* `s` there, but the one already used in `s`. This can be done by enabling `ScopedTypeVariables`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

data T s = T (s -> s)

--     vvvvvvvv  explicit here
foo :: forall s. T s -> s -> s
foo (T f) x = bar x where
    --     vvvvvv  same as above here
    bar :: s -> s
    bar a = f a
```

However, there are some tricks to get rid of `ScopedTypeVariables`. For example the following in this case:

```
data T s = T (s -> s)

foo :: T s -> s -> s
foo (T f) x = (bar `asTypeOf` idType x) x where

    bar a = f a

    idType :: a -> a -> a
    idType a _ = a

-- For completion, definition and type of 'asTypeOf'
-- asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a
-- asTypeOf x _ = x
```

For any `x :: s` the term `idType x` has type `s -> s`, and `asTypeOf` enforces both to have the same type.

Depending on your actual code, something like this might be more or less feasible.

---

<sup>* Well, in this case, since it's possible to use `ScopedTypeVariables`, see later part of the answer.</sup>

Comment: While one could have used ``bar `typeOf` typeOf``, I find the above explicit `idType` definition much more readable. I'd probably have defined it as `idType _ a = a`, or even as `idType = undefined`, but after all its actual definition is immaterial.

Comment: I thought about `idType = undefined `, but even though we're just using its type, I wouldn't feel comfortable with a partial function in this case. But yes, `idType = asTypeOf`.

Answer (score 6):

`ScopedTypeVariables` are indeed the solution, but there's an extra requirement to use them: You must put explicit `forall`s in the type signatures declaring the variables you want to scope, like this:

```
foo :: forall s. T s -> s -> s
```

This is so that the meaning of signatures in code doesn't depend on whether the extension is enabled or not.